# How do I return table after creating?

Tags: mysql, express, mysql2

How do I return the table after creating it? After inserting in mysql2 in expressjs how do I get the entire created data?

Comment: What do you mean by returnimg the table after creating it? When you create the table, it is empty, there is nothing to return. Returning a table is basically running a select * from table.